# $timeout.cancel() is not cancelling the timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I'm running a 3 minutes timeout and in that timeout i am running another function at particular durations.But when i'm trying to cancel the timeout its still running and the function inside it is still getting executed.Here's my code

```
$scope.time = 180000;
var timer = function() {
    if ($scope.time > 0) {
        $scope.time -= 1000;
        var durations = [170000, 150000, 130000, 110000, 90000, 70000, 50000, 30000, 10000];
        if (durations.includes($scope.time)) {
            dataService.acceptNotify(payload).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.data.success === true) {
                    $mdToast.showSimple(response.data.msg);
                    $mdDialog.hide();
                    $timeout.cancel(timeout);
                }
            })
        }
        $timeout(timer, 1000);
    } else {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    }
}
var timeout = $timeout(timer, 1000);
```

Comment: Right after you cancel your timeout you set it back without storing its reference

Comment: @dev8080 i have built a countdown timer , and i need to call that $timeout(timer, 1000); on the inside to keep it running

Comment: but when you cancel timeout you only cancel the one in variable 'timeout' not the one you are starting inside the loop.

Comment: Pls try the change I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just not capturing the timer instance into your variable, hence not cancelling it.

Try changing this line in your code:

```
$timeout(timer, 1000);
```

to

```
timeout = $timeout(timer, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe timeout is happening but you are not able to observe it. I see you are calling function timer after every 1 sec with this code

```
var timeout = $timeout(timer, 1000);
```

but you are canceling it after getting the response api and in meantime there would have been many instance started which will call that many time. so actually it's cancelling but after few times. 
For example, if you get response in 20 sec, then it would be cancelled after calling api 20 times as your code is such.
I can help you with right code if you tell me what you want to do above

Comment: I have a countdown timer there that counts down to 0 , and in between that 3 minutes time i'm calling an api to observe for an event in the server.If that event happens successfully out there i will get a response.data.success = true , and when that happens i want to stop that timer. Was i able to explain properly sir ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove below code which you are using above else block.

```
$timeout(timer, 1000);
```

It will work for you.